# Multiline js chart with support for irregular plot intervals

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Does anyone know of a js chart that can plot multiple lines that can have different plot intervals? I can only find HighCharts but need an Open Source one. A great example of what I'm looking for is available on highcharts demo page:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-timeline

Thanks

Comment: Highcharts is free for non-commercial - [more info](http://shop.highsoft.com/faq#Non-Commercial-0)

Comment: @KacperMadej I need one for commercial use. I've found C3.js to be the closest thing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have use Google charts in the past, they are pretty easy to inject in your code, and they support multiline. Check em out.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Comment: I've tried google charts but it's the same story where you can't have irregular intervals. All data sets must have the same number of data points and will all use the same intervals